# asp.net module deploy problems

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I'm trying to install asp.net http module on my hosting server wich i don't control, ( it has asp.net 4.0 frameworkd and IIS v7.5 installed ). so far i compiled locally my module.cs file (i compiled it with visual studio 2010 Publish Web option)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class myModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public myModule() { }

        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.EndRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
        }

        private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpContext context = application.Context;
            context.Response.Write("msg from EndRequest<br>");
        }
        public void Dispose() { }

    }

}
```

and uplouded that compiled .dll to servers webroot/bin folder, and i changed webroot/web.config file to include

```
<system.webServer>
       <modules>
          <add name="myModule" type="MyNamespace.myModule"/>
       </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

and than nothing happened. what's wrong with it, how to debugg it?

EDIT: just found out that im running in classic mode. and it works fo web.config corrected for that mode. sorry for that my head is broken.

Comment: no, and i don't understand why. i did like it says on msdn and learn.iis.net

Comment: Is there another config section where all modules are removed?

Comment: no, this is my web.config on local machine: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="myModule" type="MyNamespace.myModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration> and it doesn't work.

Comment: on remote hosting server i can see only webroot/web.config and it doesn't removes modules either. nor web.config-s in subfolders does remove modules

Comment: Have you tried using `HttpApplication.Context.Current` instead of `HttpApplication.Context`?

Comment: this property does not exists on my machine, and it's not that anyway. i put breakpoint on that Application_EndRequest method and it never executes for some reason. (neither is Init() called)

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your web site if your hosting doesn't automatically do so.

Comment: this is not it, because it doesn't work localy either with restarted application and module.cs in project App_Code folder

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.webServer>
       <modules>
          <add name="myModule" type="MyNamespace.myModule"/>
       </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Can you change the type= part? You should use "MyNamespace.myModule, *assembly name*"